# Override UIButton's setEnabled method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2, uicontrol

In Swift, `UIControl` doesn't seem to have a `setEnabled:` method. Is there a way to detect when the control state was changed?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do something like that in your subclass:

```
override var enabled:Bool {
    didSet {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
override var isEnabled:Bool {
    didSet {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Completely forgot that we can override properties in Swift

Comment: I was wondering if we could ovveride properties in swift the moment I fell on this!!!

Comment: Just a note that you do not need to call super here - Swift does that automatically when overriding properties.

Answer (score 4):

In swift 3 it is now:

```
override var isEnabled: Bool {
    didSet {
        //Your code
    }
}
```